# When a primary key is considered to be a natural key and when it is considered to be a surrogate key?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am trying to understand when a primary key is considered to be a natural key and when it is considered to be a surrogate key. I have read that surrogate keys and natural keys have the following properties:

> A natural key is a key that is formed of attributes that already exist
>   in the real world.
>
> A surrogate key has no meaning outside the database environment.

Say I have the following table (`employee_id` is the primary key):

[image]

Now let's say that `employee_id` is known in the real world, for example: each employee has an ID card which has the `employee_id` printed on it, does that mean that `employee_id` is a natural key?

Now let's consider another scenario, where `employee_id` is not known in the real world (it has no meaning outside the database environment), and the employees are identified in the real world using their `SSN`, does that mean that `employee_id` is a surrogate key?

Comment: Your quoted definition of "natural key" is comon but many would use a definition without "already"; then even if externally visible ids are new with the database, they're still natural. People who use your "already" definition likely use a definition of "surrogate" that is different from what you gave, as "new" rather than "internal", and would call new employee ids not natural but surrogate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your summary is correct. All keys are "surrogates" for the things they identify. The only useful distinction relevant to database management is whether the key attributes exist or are intended to be used *in the business domain* (AKA the domain of discourse). If a key is used in the business domain then it is called a natural key (alternatively called a business key or domain key). Otherwise it is called a surrogate key.

These terms are somewhat informal however, and do get used in subtly different ways by different people.

E.F.Codd in his RM/T paper used a stricter definition of surrogates. He proposed the idea of a "key" that was not even visible in database tables. His proposal has some serious problems with it and is not widely implemented in the way he described. It is mostly of historical interest only.

One aspect of Codd's definition that is still relevant is the idea that surrogates should generally not be visible - at least not to users of the data in the business domain. Exposing key values in the business domain in effect makes the key a domain key and not a surrogate. It follows that surrogate keys do not fulfill the role of domain keys or obviate the need for domain keys.